# instantiation of public alias template that refers to private function template fails (clang)

Tags: c++11, templates, alias, friend, clang++

I noticed some unique behaviour of Clang in the following scenario:

There is a class *foo* that contains a private member function template *function_template*.
foo also declares the non-nested struct *bar* as friend:

```
struct bar;
class foo {
    friend struct ::bar;
    template<typename T> void function_template() {}
};
```

Inside of bar the member alias template *type* is declared that refers to the return type of foo's member function template, like so:

```
struct bar {
   template<typename T> using type = decltype(foo().function_template<T>());
}
```

Using clang, the compiler is not able to instantiate the public alias template bar::type for any template argument:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
int main {
    std::cout << typeid(bar::type<int>).name() << std::endl;
    // error : 'function_template' is a private member of 'foo'
}
```

**Is this behaviour standard conforming?** MSVC and GCC both perform this instantiation. Also Clang performs the instantiation of other alias templates referring to private members of a friend class.

My extended test of the alias template behaviour can be found here:
https://ideone.com/cdB5lZ

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. But I think this should work:
```
template<typename T> using type11 = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<foo>().function_template<T>())>::type;
```

Comment: @csguth I checked it -- the instantiation fails also in this case